# <form> with just one <input> GET automatically

Tags: html, input, get

```
<form id="login_form">
    <input type="text" name="forgot_email" placeholder="Email">
    <button id="forgot_button" type="button">Send</button>
</form>
```

This is my form, it's not meant to send anywhere, not POST or GET, just being a form. The POST is handled by my jquery $.post function.
But when i click ENTER inside of the INPUT it acts like a GET to the same page. The URL changes to "localhost/xxx.php?forgot_email="

This only happens when it's just ONE input field, not with multiple input fields, but here I only want one input field and NOT a GET to the same page...

Is it a way to fix this..? I'm so confused right now, this is simple HTML. (nothing wrong with my jquery, it acts the same way when jquery is disabled)

Comment: i don't think that form is going to get submitted by a `type="button"` button, regardless of how many inputs are there.

Comment: @TilwinJoy - "*when I click ENTER inside the INPUT*" This will submit the form. Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/x7yCZ/

Comment: I fix that with my Jquery later, the problem is when i click enter inside of the input it sends a get function to the same page with the attribute value of the input.

Comment: @JaredFarrish oops. good catch.

Comment: You need to prevent the `submit` on the form.

Comment: Is it a way to disable this behaviour?

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form id="login_form" onsubmit="return false;">
    <input type="text" name="forgot_email" placeholder="Email">
    <button id="forgot_button" type="button">Send</button>
</form>
```

This will avoid your form from being sent to the server.

Comment: Helped me, could have used <div> maybe, but I'm a noob ;)

Answer (score 1):

Replace your button with a submit button and bind your JavaScript to the form's `submit` event instead of the button's `click` event. Your JS will then fire no matter which method the user uses to trigger the form.

Make sure you [prevent the default action](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) of the submit event so the browser doesn't load a new page.

Comment: won't `onsubmit="return false;` prevent submission..?

Comment: @TilwinJoy — It will, but that's a dirty hack. It is better to handle attempts to submit the form with useful behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If using jquery `$('button id or class').click(function(){return false;});`

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider wrapping the inputs in a `div` instead of a `form`, since you're not using any of it's features. It also saves you the effort of disabeling the submit button's default event like Quentin suggested.